# Forma passiva versus si passivante

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentences

C'è qualche differenza di uso tra il "si passivante" e la "forma passiva" in frasi come, per esempio, queste?

> Ho fatto alcune composizioni del tipo che si possono chiedere in
>   questi esami.

> Ho fatto alcune composizioni del tipo che possono essere chieste in
>   questi esami.

Comment: Non credo che la prima frase rappresenti l'uso del *si* passivante.

Comment: Anche, ometterei "del tipo" in entrambe.

Comment: "Ho fatto" non mi piace. Userei "Ho preparato", invece.

Comment: La riformulazione più carina è, per me, questa: 'Ho preparato alcune composizioni che possono chiedersi in questi esami.'

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Il *chiedersi* a me, suona un po' male. Io direi *che possono essere chieste in questi esami*, o anche *da chiedere in questi esami*.

Comment: Nel primo caso chi parla è uno degli esaminatori, nel secondo è uno degli esaminandi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La domanda è se vi siano differenze nell'**uso** tra la *costruzione del si passivante* e altre *costruzioni passive*.

La [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/costruzione-passiva_(Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano)/) ci spiega come vengono usate le varie costruzioni ma non ci dice molto sulle differenze nell'uso. Similmente il blog della [Zanichelli](http://www.zanichellibenvenuti.it/wordpress/?p=4024).

A mio avviso, mantenendo la struttura proposta, la frase si può scrivere equivalentemente nei modi seguenti, senza che ad orecchio si avvertano differenze significative:

> Ho svolto alcune composizioni del tipo che (normalmente) vien[e] chiesto in questi esami
>
> Ho svolto alcune composizioni del tipo che (normalmente) può venir[e] chiesto in questi esami
>
> Ho svolto alcune composizioni del tipo che (normalmente) si chiede in questi esami
>
> Ho svolto alcune composizioni del tipo che (normalmente) si può chiedere in questi esami
>
> Ho svolto alcune composizioni del tipo che (normalmente) può chiedersi in questi esami

Da notare che "tipo" è singolare - io in questo caso userei il singolare. Un ulteriore quesito potrebbe essere: «questo tipo di esami si chiede» o «questo tipo di esami si chiedono»? Ma questa è tutta un'altra domanda e forse meriterebbe un approfondimento a parte. Se si accetta la *sillessi, la costruzione a senso*, si può anche dire

> Ho svolto alcune composizioni del tipo che (normalmente) vengon[o] chieste in questi esami
>
> Ho svolto alcune composizioni del tipo che (normalmente) posson[o] venir[e] chieste in questi esami
>
> Ho svolto alcune composizioni del tipo che (normalmente) si chiedono in questi esami
>
> Ho svolto alcune composizioni del tipo che (normalmente) si posson[o] chiedere in questi esami
>
> Ho svolto alcune composizioni del tipo che (normalmente) posson[o] chiedersi in questi esami

Comment: Aggiungerei per completezza – anche se non è una costruzione passiva/passivante – che a volte si direbbe anche qualcosa come: «Ho svolto alcune composizioni del tipo che (normalmente) chiedono/possono chiedere in questi esami».

Comment: La questione dell'accordo del verbo nella frase subordinata è interessante. Cercherò di porre anche questa domanda.