# Accordo del verbo in una frase introdotta da "del tipo che"

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentences, grammatical-number, agreement

Questa domanda è stata suggerita da [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/2320/707).

Come si deve fare l'accordo del verbo in una frase subordinata introdotta da un'espressione della forma "sostantivo plurale" + "del tipo che" + "si passivante" ("che" è l'oggetto della frase) o "forma passiva" ("che" è il soggetto della frase)?

Ad esempio, queste frasi sono corrette?

> Si tratta di esercizi del tipo che normalmente *si chiedono* in questi esami.
>
> Si tratta di esercizi del tipo che normalmente *vengono chiesti* in questi esami.

Oppure si dovrebbe coniugare il verbo della subordinata al singolare in questo modo?

> Si tratta di esercizi del tipo che normalmente *si chiede* in questi esami.
>
> Si tratta di esercizi del tipo che normalmente *viene chiesto* in questi esami.

Comment: Non so se sia riuscita a esprimere bene la domanda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indipendentemente da subordinate e forme passive, si tratta come accennato in precedenza di [*concordanze a senso*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/concordanza-a-senso_(La-grammatica-italiana)/) che, secondo me, più che solo *a senso* funzionano anche e forse soprattutto *ad orecchio*: a volte queste costruzioni suonano bene, a volte no, a volte possono persino causare corto-circuiti logici, ambiguità.

Consideriamo le frasi seguenti. Benché corrette in entrambe le concordanze (morfologica/grammaticale e a senso), non è sempre ovvio quale sia quella che suona meglio:

1. *questo tipo di* dubbi (a) sorge / (b) sorgono anche ai più esperti --> **opterei per (a)**
2. *questo genere di* storie non (a) solletica / (b) solleticano il mio interesse --> **opterei per (a)**
3. *un esercito di* zanzare (a) infestava / (b) infestavano la zona --> **opterei per (a)**
4. (a) partecipò / (b) parteciparono *un sacco di* persone --> **opterei per (b)**
5. ci (a) vuole / (b) vogliono *un mucchio di* soldi per permettersi una villa così --> **opterei per (b)**
6. *un paio di* cucchiaini (a) è / (b) sono anche (a) troppo (b) troppi --> **opterei per (b)**
7. non (a) basterà / (b) basteranno *una decina di* esempi --> **opterei per (a)**
8. *una dozzina di* monetine (a) fu / (b) furono tutto ciò che servì --> **opterei per (b)**
9. *un centinaio di* centesimi (a) fa / (b) fanno un euro --> **opterei per (a)**
10. *un migliaio di* soldati (a) si diresse / (b) diressero verso il confine --> **opterei per (b)**
11. *la maggior parte di* loro non se ne (a) rende / (b) rendono conto --> **opterei per (a)**
12. *una gran quantità di* specie animali (a) è / (b) sono a rischio di estinzione --> **opterei per (a)**
13. *un piccolo numero di* industrie (a) si spartiva / (b) si spartivano il mercato --> **opterei per (b)**
14. (a) c'era / (b) c'erano solo *un gruppetto di* studenti --> **opterei per (a)**
15. *una manciata di* esercenti (a) rimase / (b) rimasero (a) aperta (b) aperti --> **opterei per (b)**
16. *un oceano di* emozioni in tempesta le si (a) frastornava / (b) frastornavano dentro --> **opterei per (b)**
17. la (a) travolgeva / (b) travolgevano *un uragano di* sensazioni contrastanti --> **opterei per (a)**
18. *una folla di* fan deliranti (a) spingeva (b) spingevano per uscire --> **opterei per (a)**
19. si (a) presentò / (b) presentarono alla prova *una moltitudine di* candidati --> **opterei per (a)**
20. (a) seguì / (b) seguirono *una serie di* tentativi disastrosi --> **opterei per (a)**
21. gli anni seguenti (a) fu / (b) furono *una successione di* insuccessi --> **opterei per (b)**
22. non (a) fu / (b) furono *una sequenza di* provocazioni, ma vero e proprio mobbing --> **opterei per (a)**
23. (a) s'era / (b) s'erano (a) vista / (b) visti passare *una sfilata di* personaggi equivoci --> **opterei per (b)**
24. allo stadio (a) sventolò / (b) sventolarono *un tripudio di* tricolori --> **opterei per (b)**

Si provi a fare quest'esercizio ogni due/tre giorni e si noterà che, tranne eccezioni, le risposte varieranno sensibilmente: un giorno una costruzione suonerà bene e un altro la stessa costruzione suonerà meno bene. Si provino anche a modificare lievemente gli esempi sopra e si noterà che la stessa costruzione suona meglio o peggio anche a seconda del contesto.

La costruzione specifica proposta su - sostantivo plurale seguito dalla locuzione "*del tipo che*" - secondo me genera ancor più dubbi. Tecnicamente però è corretto usare sia il singolare (concordanza morfologica/grammaticale) che il plurale (concordanza a senso).

Answer (score 5):

Le due coppie di frasi sono entrambe corrette, ciò che cambia è a cosa si riferisce il pronome relativo "che":

- Nella prima coppia di frasi, sostituisce "esercizi" (Dividendo le due proposizioni, otteniamo: Si tratta di esercizi del tipo. Gli esercizi si chiedono/vengono chiesti normalmente in questi esami);
- Nella seconda, rimpiazza "tipo" (Si tratta di esercizi del tipo. Il tipo [di esercizi] si chiede/viene chiesto normalmente in questi esami).

Comment: Per quanto la prima coppia di frasi sia corretta "a orecchio", non credo che sia particolarmente sensata, a un'analisi più approfondita: il complemento *del tipo* sembra essere superfluo. È così?

Comment: Secondo la mia modestissima opinione, "del tipo" indica, in questo contesto, che negli esami non vengono necessariamente chiesti gli esercizi di cui si sta parlando nello specifico, ma altri della medesima tipologia. Tuttavia, forse sarebbe più appropriato utilizzare "Si tratta di esercizi *dello stesso tipo*"